# How do i dynamically populate an ion-select with an array which was selected from a previous ion-select

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular8, ngfor

So I'm getting an array of objects which are categories with attributes such as id, name and subccategory.

I've used an *ngFor to populate the first ion-select and thats fine.

I need to know how to populate the second ion-select with the subcatagories from selected category(First ion-select) 
Iv tried to pass the selected value as an array but im obviously doing something wrong, please help!

```
    <ion-row class="filterItems" color="primary">
    <ion-label>Category</ion-label>
    <ion-select>
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let catagory of catagories">
        {{ catagory.category }}
      </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-label>Sub Category</ion-label>
    <ion-select>
      <ion-select-option>{{Need the subcatagorys in here}} </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(ionChange)` event to populate your sub category array.

```
<ion-row class="filterItems" color="primary">
    <ion-label>Category</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selecTedValue" (ionChange)="selectCategory(selecTedValue)">  // pass your selecTedValue ngModel as parameter
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let catagory of catagories" value="{{category}}">
        {{ catagory.category }}
      </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-label>Sub Category</ion-label>
    <ion-select>
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let subCat of sub_category">{{subCat.subCategoryNameOrValue}} </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-row>
```

Inside your page.ts take a variable for subcategory.

```
sub_category:any;


selectCategory(catagory){
  this.sub_category = category; //populate here
}
```